# How to do a naked function and inline assembler in x64 Visual C++

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, assembly

I am proxying a method call in using a naked function and inline assembler.

```
__declspec(naked) void ProxyFunction()
{
    static const unsigned int addressofRealFunction = 0x0041b200;
    __asm
    {
        jmp [addressofRealFunction];
    }
}
```

How can I translate this to x64?  In visual studio there is no inline assembler or naked functions for x64.

Naked removes the assembly prologue and epilogue.  I need this to make sure the stack frame stays equivalent for the call.

What would you do?

Comment: What would *I* do?  I'd use a better compiler, for example gcc or clang support `__attribute__((naked))` and inline asm (using different syntax than MSVC though).

Answer (score 4):

If Microsoft's advise to use masm for tasks like this does not work for you, then one way is to look into allocating a page, set the executable attribute on it, then place the opcodes there using direct memory writes at an offset starting at the beginning of the page.

Answer (score 2):

Try compiling it straight:

```
void ProxyFunction()
{
    RealFunction();
}
```

See if the compiler optimizes it down to bare jump. It might.

Comment: One issue is the proxied function may have arguments passed in registers or the stack. I cannot call RealFunction with arguments since it is unknown, have to jmp to it and assume the caller of the proxy set up the proper calling convention.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish in the first place?

Comment: It *absolutely* will compile it to a jump, and it will do this for both x86-32 and x86-64 builds. As such, this is the way you should *always* write it. [The original code using inline asm is slower and larger, thus actually a pessimization](http://archives.miloush.net/michkap/archive/2005/05/11/416624.html). I cannot imagine why it would be a problem that this wouldn't be optimized in a debug build, @han. It'll be a `call` instruction instead. That means it'll be slower, but functionally identical. In a debug build, who cares?

Comment: This will fail miserably without optimizations or when flags like -RTCs or -JMC are used.