# Visual Studio 2019 x64 c++ .asm file - use macros from different file

Tags: visual-studio, assembly, macros, c-preprocessor, masm

I got a tricky situation. I got a project with an `.asm` file that do some logic. I got a macro `#define`ed in a different `.h` file in the project.

Is it possible to use the macro in the `.asm` file?

What I tried so far is this in the header file

`#define MOVRAX "mov rax, rcx"`

and then something like this in the asm:

```
PUBLIC test_fn

.CODE
     
test_fn PROC
    MOVRAX
test_fn ENDP

END
```

which sadly doesnt compile... is there any way to do that?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6166544/5910058

Comment: that is not remotely what I asked about. I already got a working `asm` file - which is not inline. I want to use macros in that file.

Comment: It wasn't an answer. Just a comment with a reference I thought might be useful to you. If it's not; just ignore it.

Comment: Does the macro need to be a C macro for some reason?  Also the quotes in the macro expansion would result in illegal assembly syntax, so are they necessary for some reason?

Comment: no, the macro should be just `mov rax, rcx`, it was a typo on my side

Comment: This has nothing to do with C++.

Comment: I'm not following the requirement here.  Why would you have `mov rax, rcx` in a c++ macro?  It obviously can't ever be used in c++ code?  masm has [macros](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/assembler/masm/macro?view=vs-2019).  Perhaps you could put your macro in a file specifically intended for asm, then have your asm files [include](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/assembler/masm/include-masm?view=vs-2019) it?  Failing that, I suppose you could try to manually invoke the c++ preprocessor against an asm file.  Seems risky though.

Comment: Why would you expect that to compiler?  It doesn't contain a `#include "foo.h"` line so even if you did set up your build to run that file through the C preprocessor before assembling (like GCC will with `.S` files), it won't have the macro defined.  Unless you define it on the command line like `cc -E "-DMOVRAX=mov rax, rcx" foo.asm`